# Upload, Save and read word (.docx) file c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ms-word

I need to save microsoft word file on my mvc 4 site server. What I am currently doing is save the .docx file using the following code:

```
path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(subPath), System.IO.Path.GetFileName("story_chapter" + DateTime.Now.ToBinary() + ".docx"));
chapFile.SaveAs(path);
```

and opening the doc with following code:

```
Application word = new Application();
Document doc = new Document();

((_Document)doc).Close();
((_Application)word).Quit();

List<string> data = new List<string>();
try
{
     object fileName = path;
     // Define an object to pass to the API for missing parameters
     object missing = System.Type.Missing;
     doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

     String read = string.Empty;
     for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
     {
          string temp = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
          if (temp != string.Empty)
                 data.Add(temp);
     }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {

  }
  finally {

       ((_Document)doc).Close();
       ((_Application)word).Quit();
  }
```

the thing is, I'm able to save the file just fine, and for once, the file was read and displayed successfully too. But then, i started receiving errors like "doc is already opened in normat.doc" or something like that and the program gets stuck on the following line:

```
doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

I have deduced that maybe im saving the file the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use interop on a server, don't "double dot" into COM objects, dispose everything.

Comment: I don't see an explicit doc.Save(); command? And you need to do doc = null; word = null; at the end to release the COM objects. In addition, you should explicitly do GC.Collect(); and the GC with PendingFinalizers (sorry, on a mobile device so I can't look up the exact line of code) - twice. If you continue to have problems, please quote the EXACT error message.

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you. I'll give it a shot.